# ActiveStorage Thumbnail Persistence

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I have migrated my Rails app to 5.2.0. Before I was using Paperclip. Paperclip generates different variants like thumbnail and avatar when an image is uploaded. How can I achieve this with ActiveStorage? I know we can do this `user.avatar.variant(resize_to_fit: [100, 100])` but to me it's like doing this over and over again. I'm aiming to do pre-processing of these variants once it's uploaded.

Also you guys can suggest a better technique if this is bad from your experience.

Comment: You are in the right way but you need to include one just method to your code `.processed` so it should appear as the following: `user.avatar.variant(resize_to_fit: [100, 100]).processed`

Comment: Does it mean after I call user.avatar.variant(resize_to_fit: [100, 100]).processed, it will be saved into disk and next time it will just return the variant without reworking. How can I use the variant next time? Is it user.avatar.variant(resize_to_fit: [100, 100]) or user.avatar.variant(resize_to_fit: [100, 100]).processed?

Comment: you are right, it will save the variant and always use it, you always should include `.processed` to use the saved variant. If you want to refresh/regenerate the variant, then you can use the code without `.processed`

Comment: this is the link to the docs http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Variant.html

Comment: @TrongBang if the upvoted answer below solved your issue or helped you, can you mark it as the solution? Thank you!

Answer (score 20):

Using `.processed` is the correct way to check if that variant was already processed and uploaded to the storage service.

One thing that Paperclip did nicely was the `styles: {}` object, in which you could list all the different transformations you wanted to do for thumbnails, etc, and name them.

Here's how I am handling named & stored transformations. This also keeps my template syntax shorter:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one_attached :image_file

  def self.sizes
    {
      thumbnail: { resize: "100x100" },
      hero1:     { resize: "1000x500" }
    }
  end

  def sized(size)
    self.image_file.variant(Image.sizes[size]).processed
  end

end
```

Then in a template, say I have `@image`, I can simply call `@image.sized(:hero1)`

Comment: just a wee note:  no need for `return`

Comment: @aenw fair point. I like including `return`, it soothes my frazzled brain, but given that it is not the "Ruby way" I will remove it from my answer.

Answer (score 1):

@aguardientico is correct that by add the `.processed` method to your variant object which will use the blob key to check if the file already exists on your service before attempting to re-produce the whole process again.

Also something to know in addition is the `resize_to_fit` is a ImageProcessing gem transformation method and is not supported yet by Rails 5.2. Instead right now it uses MiniMagick where you would append `>` to the `resize` method for paperclip.

so rewritten it would look like `user.avatar.variant(resize: "100x100>")`